# Why does squaring a matrix with direct food sources show indirect food sources?

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix that shows a food web and what certain animals eat. the columns represent the animal that is being eaten and the rows represent which animal is eating it. e.g. [direct food matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxvtX.png). this matrix shows the direct food sources which is when animal directly eats another. indirect food sources are when an animal eats another through another animal. e.g. an eagle eats a fox which eats insects so the eagle indirectly eats insects. [indirect food source matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKsrj.png). the indirect food source matrix is just the direct one squared. how does this work? how does squaring the direct food sources give the indirect ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). Consider if "fox eats organism" and "organism eats insects" then $A_{\text{fox,organism}}=1;A_{\text{organism,insect}}=1$ and
$A^2 = \sum_j A_{ij} A_{jk}$ hence $A^2_{\text{fox, insect}} = \sum_{\text{all organisms}}A_{\text{fox,organism}} A_{\text{organism, insect}}$ and this will be non zero as long as there is at least one organism that "fox eats organism" and "organism eats insects".

Comment: How exactly does this work though? how does squaring it give indirect sources, that part im not getting.

Comment: Think of it as a hop: A tells you who you can reach in one hop. Hopping again is like applying A again. So to reach j from i in 2 hops, you first make one hop to an intermidiary k, and then hop from k to j.